# Is this the correct async approach for waiting for a property to be set?

Tags: c#, async-await

I have a class property that is set by a background operation. This is my method that reads the value for that property. The idea is wait a reasonable amount of time before returning null since that means there is still work in progress about to complete

```
public async Task<Entity> GetEntityAsync()
{
    int tries = 0;
    while (_entity == null && tries < 2)
    {
        await Task.Delay(100);
        tries++;
    }

    return _entity;
}
```

Then I use it like this

```
var entity = await entityManager.GetEntityAsync();
```

Is this approach correct or there is any better option?

**EDIT**

The background operation that sets `_entity` is a third party component that reports trough an event that data is available. I want to translate the event approach to an async/await method. Reasons for this are

- This method is used on many places (I'm doing a refactoring) and it's not prepared for an event oriented approach.
- Event oriented approach is more complex to implement. I just want to make sure I don't hang the main thread, 99% of the times, `_entity` will have a value different to null on first shoot.

Comment: how is `_entity` handled ? where you set it's value ?

Comment: Can your property setter not just fire an event after it is set? Also, it's not really async if you are *waiting* for it to finish

Comment: @EhsanSajjad: there is a background thread that will eventually set it. Mainly want to know if there is any bug on the logic of that method, not very confident of my async/await skills

Comment: @musefan: don't want to handle with events, I want to call a method and get the value if any

Comment: you should be awaiting that thread in the GetEntity

Comment: @EhsanSajjad: added how I would be using that method. Just want to know if there is a nonsense in my code or a better simplification.

Comment: @musefan: I don't want to hang the main thread waiting for `_entity`, I thought this could help. That's my main objective, not interested on real async

Comment: Why is the operation not returning the value it computes, and instead just setting a variable?

Comment: @Servy: added more information on my edit

Comment: @StackOverflower That problem in no way explains why you'd need to do this.

Comment: @Servy: how you would do it assuming I don't want to change this to a event driven approach? I see a lot of people in anger, but can't see what's wrong...and that's why I made the question: to validate my approach and get a fix in case there was any.

Comment: @StackOverflower You can simply [ask google](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=create%20task%20from%20event%20c%23) and see plenty of examples of how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said that your data source uses an event to return the `_entity`. Events are quite easily wired into a `TaskCompletionSource`. Consider:

```
public Task<Data> GetDataAsync()
{
  var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<Data>();

  dataSource.DataReturned += d => tcs.SetResult(d);

  return tcs.Task;
}
```

Now you have a nice little asynchronous method wired to your data sources event.

Of course, this is just a very simple example that makes a lot of assumptions, no error handling etc., but it should put you on the way to a good solution. No need for polling if you have events :)

Comment: You need unsubscribe from dataSource.DataReturned to avoid a memory leak.

Comment: @Ive Yes, that's in one of the assumptions - that `dataSource` isn't persistent. Not just for the memory leak, there's more important issues in this case :)

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is not reliable.

You should be awaiting the `entityManager.GetEntityAsync()`  method in the `GetEntityAsync()` method for that :

```
public async Task<Entity> GetEntityAsync()
{
    _entity = await entityManager.GetEntityAsync();
    return _entity
}
```

Comment: It's not valid to await on a property getter, that's just disallowed on compilation time

Comment: @StackOverflower Then don't make it a property; make it a method.

Comment: @Servy: that's what I have, a method (GetEntityAsync). Please check my edit

Comment: we are awaiting in method not property getter

Comment: @Ehsan Sajjad: correct, but before you're edition you suggested to await on property getter, that's why I said I can't do that

Comment: i agree, but the code i wrote was contradicting my statement, i missed something surely

Answer (score 0):

Define your _entity like:

```
TaskCompletionSource<Entity> _entity =  _new TaskCompletionSource<Entity>();
```

and set it like this on 3rd. party event:

```
_entity.TrySetResult(xxxx);
```

Then use it like this:

```
public async Task<Entity> GetEntityAsync()
{
    Entity result = await _entity.Task;
    _entity = _new TaskCompletionSource<Entity>();
    return result;
}
```